# Check whether input field is empty in Controller - AngularJS

Tags: angularjs

I just started learning AngularJS. In a testing program I wrote, I need to check whether my input field is empty or not inside the controller(script).

Following is the code I wrote

```
<div ng-controller="ExampleController">
    <input type="text" ng-model="userFirstName" required/><br>
    <p ng-bind="msg"></p>
</div>

<script>
    var mainApp = angular.module("mainApp", []);
    mainApp.controller('ExampleController', function ($scope) {

       if($scope.userFirstName.length === 0){
          $scope.msg = "pls enter something";
       }else{
          $scope.msg = "Something Entered";
       }
    });
</script>
```

Here, as the output, I expected to see `pls enter something`. But I cannot see anything.

But If I change the script in to following with some small changes, it shows me `Something Entered` as expected.

```
<script>
   var mainApp = angular.module("mainApp", []);
   mainApp.controller('ExampleController', function ($scope) {
        $scope.userFirstName = 'Something';
        if($scope.userFirstName.length === 0){
             $scope.msg = "pls enter something";
        }else{
             $scope.msg = "Something Entered";
        }
   });
</script>
```

What is wrong here? As far as I understand, the first one should work if the second one works as expected. Otherwise, both should not work.

I think I have not understood something very basic. If so, please describe me what I have not read about.

Thank You..!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that you are only checking if the scope property is filled in once. (this happens when angular initializes the controller)
What you need to do is add an ng-change to the html and then when the model changes the function will fire again.

In the function you do your logic again. like so :

```
var mainApp = angular.module("mainApp", []);
   mainApp.controller('ExampleController', function ($scope) {
        $scope.userFirstName = '';
        $scope.checkContent = function(){
          if($scope.userFirstName.length === 0 || typeof $scope.userFirstName === 'undefined'){
             $scope.msg = "pls enter something";
          }else{
             $scope.msg = "Something Entered";
           }
         } 

   });
```

then in your html:

```
<div ng-controller="ExampleController">
    <input type="text" ng-change="checkContent()" ng-model="userFirstName" required/><br>
    <p ng-bind="msg"></p>
</div>
```

Comment: only works for 'something entered'. When the text box is cleared, it does not work as expected

Comment: @vigamage I updated my answer I think you will need to do an undefined or null check. Kind regards

Comment: yes, that is it. length check is not needed I think.

Answer (score 1):

well, `.length` works with an array. here you don't have type of `$scope.userFirstName` as an array.

modify it like

```
<div ng-controller="ExampleController">
  <input type="text" ng-model="userFirstName" required="" />
  <br />
  <p ng-bind="msg"></p>
</div>
<script>
  var mainApp = angular.module("mainApp", []);
  mainApp.controller('ExampleController', function ($scope) {
    $scope.userFirstName = '';
     if($scope.userFirstName === ''){
        $scope.msg = "pls enter something";
     }else{
        $scope.msg = "Something Entered";
     }
  });
</script>
```

Please find plunker here: https://plnkr.co/edit/7gc3fj8apFJnE2wNJbQ7?p=preview

Hope it helps you!

Comment: Thank you for the tip of 'length'. But this solution does not work

Answer (score 0):

try with this one, create function and call it on Change event

```
if(!$scope.userFirstName || $scope.userFirstName == null){
                $scope.msg = "pls enter something";
            }else{
                $scope.msg = "Something Entered";
            }
```

Answer (score 0):

```
var mainApp = angular.module("mainApp", []);
mainApp.controller('ExampleController', function ($scope) {
    $scope.userFirstName = '';
    $scope.checkContent = function(){
        if($scope.userFirstName)//Check Empty Field
        {
            $scope.msg = "pls enter something";
        }else{
            $scope.msg = "Something Entered";
        }
    } 

});
```